# magento link to cms page in product attribute not working

Tags: magento, url, attributes

I'm trying to add an 'a href' / link in an Attribute Field for a product.
However, the methods that I'm using are not working - although they work in CMS page content. When I view the product, the attribute with the link is displayed, but the actual URL does not seem to be generated correctly (404 error)

I've tried the following:

```
1. <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>test-page">Test link 1</a>
2. <a href="{{store url='test-page'}}">Test link 2</a> 
3. <a href="index.php/test-page">Test link 3</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Your help is appreciated in advance

Thank you!

Comment: What URL is actually generated (view page source)? Also, make sure, that your attribute allows html-tags in frontend (you can ensure this via attribute-management in the backend).

Comment: What is your field type?

Comment: Field type: Text Field. HTML Tags on Frontend: Yes.

Comment: When I inspect the a href element, it looks exactly as my methods above, i.e. the echos or {} have not been generated: <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>test-page">Test link 1</a>

Comment: Why not save only the URL (or only CMS page URL key without the base URL) instead of the whole anchor tag? Can you post here what you are viewing in source view please?

Comment: From Source code: <a href=​"<?php echo Mage:​:​getBaseUrl()​;​ ?>partquip-steering-and-suspension-info-pages">​Info pages test​</a>​.            Also, the reason I'm going for anchor tags is because we do not want to display the entire url, just a text link.

Comment: This is still not working.... it seems that for some odd reason if I use the php echo for Mage::getBaseURL(), it doesn't get 'fired' and on closer inspection in code view the tags are all converted like this: &lt;?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?&gt;partquip-steering-and-suspension-info-pages">...... What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2):

Magento EAV attributes values will not be parsed by PHP on their own. For display to the user, they are rendered through a frontend model. See `eav_attribute` table for examples.

Based on the "we do not want to display the entire url, just a text link" comment, you need an attribute with a custom frontend model. I'm guessing that it was added via the Admin Panel, which won't allow to add custom frontend models. Whereas adding the frontend model requires a script, I'd recommend adding the attribute via script in the first place.

To install this attribute properly , Magento needs to execute a **setup script**, which is a Magento term for (usually) PHP code which is executed exactly once with the ability to manipulate the database. Running these presupposes a module exists:

*app/etc/modules/Your_Module.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Your/Module/etc/config.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <your_module>
                <class>Your_Module_Model</class>
            </your_module>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <your_module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Your_Module</module>
                </setup>
            </your_module_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Your/Module/sql/your_module_setup/install-1.0.0.0.php*:

```
<?php

$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->startSteup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    'catalog_product',
    'unique_attr_code',
    array(
        'label'     => 'Link to Product',
        'required'  => 'false',             //or true if appropriate
        'group'     => 'General',           //Adds to all sets
        'frontend'  => 'your_module/frontend_url'
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

*app/code/local/Your/Module/Model/Frontend/Url.php*:

```
class Your_Module_Model_Frontend_Url
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Abstract
{
    public function getUrl($object)
    {
        $url = false;
        if ($path = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode())) {
            $url = Mage::getUrl('path');
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```